# Contour Polygons to 3D

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, 3d, contour

I am trying to make a 3D representation of the map below. I have 3 polygons which represent contour lines. It starts at 0ft for the outside polygon, 10ft in the middle and 20ft for the very center polygon. The end result would look something like a weird shaped pancake that is 20ft thick within the middle polygon and shrinks down to 0ft at the very edges. As an end result I would like to be able to compute the volume of the end shape. I am using ArcGIS10.3.1. I do not think I have the 3D Analyst extension so that may be a problem.

[image]

Comment: The 3D Analyst extension is what provides ArcScene, so yeah, without it you're not going to be making 3D representations in ArcGIS.

Comment: Do you need the visual 3D representation, or do you only need to calculate the volume of the shape? A simple estimate can be done like this: `[(Area of 0ft contour)-(Area of 10ft contour)]*5+(Area of 10ft contour)*10+[(Area of 10ft contour)-(Area of 20ft contour)]*5+(Area of 20ft contour)*10`.